# Comparing date and time selected from picker and with current date and time

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im using a date and time picker.using the below code i'm fetching the time and date from picker and it is showing current date and time in console.

```
- (void)eventForDatePicker:(id)sender {



    UIDatePicker *datePicker = (UIDatePicker *)sender;  

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle; 
   [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"]; 
   // [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
// [df setDateFormat:@"dd hh-mm-ss"];

  //  message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", df];

   message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", 
                           [df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]]; 
    NSLog(@"%@sssssssssssssssssfff",message);



    NSUserDefaults *prefs4 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs4 setObject:message forKey:@"name"];
    [prefs4   synchronize];




-(void)switchChanged:(id)sender {

NSUserDefaults *prefs5 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *mess = [prefs5 stringForKey:@"name"];



        [datearray addObject:mess];



        NSLog(@"is isssssss%@",datearray);


        NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        [currentDefaults setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:datearray] forKey:@"datesaving"];
        [currentDefaults synchronize];



}    

  //Now in anotherview , retrieving the contents in date array and by calling a function a text is displaying.
  NSDate* date = [NSDate date];

    //Create the dateformatter object

    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

    //Set the required date format

    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];

    //Get the string date

     str = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

    //Display on the console

    NSLog(@"fdf %@",str);




    NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *dataRepresentingSavedArray = [currentDefaults2 objectForKey:@"datesaving"];
    NSMutableArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingSavedArray];

    if(oldSavedArray!=nil){
    datess = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];


    }





       NSLog(@"%doooooooooooooooo",[datess count]);

       NSLog(@"%@llllllllllll111111111111",datess);





-(void)check1
{
      //NSLog(@"%@llllllllllll",[datess objectAtIndex:0]);


    for(int j=0;j<[newinx count];j++)
    {


        if([str isEqualToString:[datess objectAtIndex:j]])
        {


                //tv.text  =[Tips objectAtIndex:day];
            tv.text=@"helloo";

        }
```

but this comparison is not working.Can anyone help me please.thanks in advance.

Comment: can you plz paste your code in which you are adding it to array and saving to user defaults?

Comment: NSLog(@"is isssssss%@",datearray);
        
        
        NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
      
        [currentDefaults setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:datearray] forKey:@"datesaving"];
        [currentDefaults synchronize];

Comment: @saadnib,this is how i saved in array

Comment: what datearray contains....date objects or string objects?

Comment: [datearray addObject:message];message is astring

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `intValue` in `NSLog(@"kykykykyky%d",[[datess objectAtIndex:0]intValue]);`? If you get rid of that (provided you have saved the message string properly in NSUserdefaults), it should print the same string as before.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you save the `NSDate` object, returned by `UIDatePicker` in `NSUserDefaults`? Just put it there & use for comparisons - no unarchiving is necessary. It will be much simpler.

And convert it with `NSDateFormatter` only if you want to display it.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
Compare the 2 dates with:

   if ([d compare:now] == NSOrderedDescending) {
        // d is later than now
   }else{
        // d is earlier than or equal to now
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are going wrong ...

```
NSLog(@"kykykykyky%d",[[datess objectAtIndex:0]intValue]);
```

your datess array contains string objects then if you want to convert it in `NSDate` objects then use `NSDateFormatter` for this.

First `NSLog` a object from your datess array as -

```
NSLog(@"date str = %@",[datess objectAtIndex:0]);
```

to confirm that date string are saving properly.

Then make a `NSDateFormatter` object and set its date format as -

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a"];
```

or you can use ant format style. Then make a `NSDate` object using this `NSDateFormatter` as

```
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[datess objectAtIndex:0]];
```

it will give you a `NSDate` object.

For comparing two `NSDate` objects use -

```
- (BOOL)date:(NSDate*)date isBetweenDate:(NSDate*)beginDate andDate:(NSDate*)endDate
{   
    if ([date compare:beginDate] == NSOrderedAscending)
        return NO;

    if ([date compare:endDate] == NSOrderedDescending) 
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: @saadnib.thanks for your great hand.what i try to do is saving all the dates and time into and array and searching whether current and time in that array and if so firing a local notification.

Comment: there is nothing wrong in that but you have to take care of one thing that in the format you are saving date and time to array you have make the date with the same format.

Comment: @saadnib.thankyou.i have edited the code but still comparison is not working.now where to change the code.

Comment: you can not compare two date string objects , i have updated my answer plz check.